# Google API returns incorrect values

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want the goal completions by page from the Analytics API. The dates are the same, and sampling is off.

**API:**

```
{ kind: 'analytics#gaData',
  id: 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:90090243&dimensions=ga:hostname,+ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:users,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:goalValueAll&start-date=2015-01-05&end-date=2015-01-05',
  query: 
   { 'start-date': '2015-01-05',
     'end-date': '2015-01-05',
     ids: 'ga:90090243',
     dimensions: 'ga:hostname, ga:pagePath',
     metrics: [ 'ga:users', 'ga:goalCompletionsAll', 'ga:goalValueAll' ],
     'start-index': 1,
     'max-results': 1000,
     samplingLevel: 'HIGHER_PRECISION' },
  itemsPerPage: 1000,
  totalResults: 10,
  selfLink: 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:12345678&dimensions=ga:hostname,+ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:users,ga:goalCompletionsAll,ga:goalValueAll&start-date=2015-01-05&end-date=2015-01-05',
  profileInfo: 
   { profileId: '12345678',
     accountId: '12345678',
     webPropertyId: 'UA-12345678-1',
     internalWebPropertyId: '12345678',
     profileName: 'All Web Site Data',
     tableId: 'ga:90090243' },
  containsSampledData: false,
  columnHeaders: 
   [ { name: 'ga:hostname',
       columnType: 'DIMENSION',
       dataType: 'STRING' },
     { name: 'ga:pagePath',
       columnType: 'DIMENSION',
       dataType: 'STRING' },
     { name: 'ga:users', columnType: 'METRIC', dataType: 'INTEGER' },
     { name: 'ga:goalCompletionsAll',
       columnType: 'METRIC',
       dataType: 'INTEGER' },
     { name: 'ga:goalValueAll',
       columnType: 'METRIC',
       dataType: 'CURRENCY' } ],
  totalsForAllResults: 
   { 'ga:users': '155',
     'ga:goalCompletionsAll': '0',
     'ga:goalValueAll': '0.0' },
  rows: 
   [ [ 'mydomain.com', '/', '1', '0', '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com',
       '/brand-business-bundle',
       '1',
       '0',
       '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com',
       '/brand-business-internet',
       '1',
       '0',
       '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com', '/business-bundle', '1', '0', '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com',
       '/business-fiber-internet',
       '22',
       '0',
       '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com', '/business-internet', '37', '0', '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com', '/business-phone', '84', '0', '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com', '/privacy-policy', '1', '0', '0.0' ],
     [ 'mydomain.com',
       '/small-business-internet',
       '6',
       '0',
       '0.0' ],
     [ 'co.lumb.co', '/', '1', '0', '0.0' ] ] }
```

Here's what I see in the Analytics dashboard:

[image: Analytics goal values by page]

Things I have tried:

- Different sampling levels (no effect)
- Removing other dimensions from the query (total is correct, but I want per-page data)
- Different dates (no effect)

Why am I getting back such low values from the API when the dashboard shows otherwise?

Comment: your request to the api 2 dimensions and 3 metrics. try and find a dashboard that uses the same dimensions and metrics.

Comment: I have tried this by requesting only pagePath and goalConversionsAll. The API returns 0 and goalConversionsAll for every page, but Analytics shows the screenshot above (80 conversions on the /business-phone page, 35 on /business-internet, etc.).

Comment: Do you have only one property in your GA? Goals are set on the property level so if you are asking for data from another property you will see nothing. Also, are you sure you are asking for the same dimension as shown in the Analytics dashboard? _(entrance)_ shouldn't be visible in the report containing page paths. It is a value usually visible in source/referrer related reports. What kind of report this screenshot comes from?

Comment: The report is Conversions > Goals > Goal URLs, and the property is correct.

I couldn't be sure if I was querying the same was as in the dashboard, because it doesn't expose that to you. I was finally able to solve the problem, and will post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most befuddling thing about this was that it worked for about 2 months and suddenly broke. I suspect a bug was introduced to the Analytics API.

The workaround is to use ga:goalCompletionLocation instead of ga:pagePath. I call it a workaround instead of a solution because you cannot combine ga:goalCompletionLocation with much else as far as metrics go.